# UIKit + SpriteKit - Cannot properly layer buttons, nodes, and image views

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview, uikit, sprite-kit

I'm quite new to iOS development, and I'm working on an app that uses UIKit for buttons and Sprite Kit for a [virtual joystick](https://github.com/TheSneakyNarwhal/SpriteKit-Joystick). My goal is to have the buttons and joystick visible on top of a UIImageView (more specifically, a [MotionJpegImageView](https://github.com/mateagar/Motion-JPEG-Image-View-for-iOS)). I used a storyboard to create the buttons, and programatically created a UIImageView and added it as a subview to my main view in my view controller. The joystick was created in a separate file that subclasses SKScene. However, there's a problem. My UIImageView shows up below the buttons (as desired) but covers the joystick. I need the joystick to be visible on top of the image. I've already tried the sendSubviewToBack method but that isn't doing the trick. I've also tried using zPositions, but that is not working either. Does anyone know how I can achieve my goal? Relevant code is below. Thanks for looking!

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://shibuya.ipcam.jp:60001/nphMotionJpeg?Resolution=320x240&Quality=Standard"];

    _imageView = [[MotionJpegImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.origin.x,
                                                                       [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width)];

    _imageView.url = url;

    [self.view addSubview:_imageView];

    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:_imageView];

    [_imageView play];

    SKView *spriteView = (SKView *) self.view;

    JoystickScene* joystick = [[JoystickScene alloc] initWithSize:CGSizeMake(768,1024)];

    [spriteView presentScene: joystick];

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:spriteView];
}
```

**JoystickScene.m**

```
- (void)didMoveToView: (SKView *) view
{
    SKSpriteNode *jsThumb = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"joystick.png"];

    SKSpriteNode *jsBackdrop = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"dpad.png"];

    joystick = [Joystick joystickWithThumb:jsThumb andBackdrop:jsBackdrop];

    joystick.position = CGPointMake(jsBackdrop.size.width, jsBackdrop.size.width);

    velocityTick = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(joystickMovement)];

    [velocityTick addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];

    joystick.zPosition = 1;

    [self addChild:joystick];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spritekit `SKView` is the view of your viewcontroller. Every subview will be rendered on top of it. Is there a special reason you want to use Spritekit for the joystick? Otherwise I would suggest to make it with standard UIKit elements and just add it after the imageView.
Using an `SKView` on top of other views will not give you the desired results, since it cannot have a transparent background.

Another issue with your code: you shouldn't create and add views in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, since this method could be called multiple times (every device Rotation for instance). Use `viewDidLoad` instead.

Comment: I'm only using SpriteKit because I can't find a joystick implementation that uses UIKit. And oh, thanks, I'll use viewDidLoad instead :)

Comment: Actually, never mind; I think I found a UIKit joystick that works: https://github.com/MattFoley/MFLJoystick